# How can I find duplicate processes on FreeBSD?

Tags: process, freebsd

I suspect that there is some **replicate** (many instances) **process** that is overloading the CPU of my FreeBSD 10.3 (pfSense v2.3) computer, but I don't know what its name could be.

The process is probably a .sh script of mine, but I have many of them, and some of them call anothers.

Is there any (preferably CLI) method to **detect these multiple instances** of the same process?

I have researched, but solutions are for Linux, and syntax is not exactly the same for some commands, like `uniq`.

Comment: Perhaps like this: `ps ax -o command | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: @SatoKatsura: What does `-o command` means?

Comment: Basically show only the command line.  `man ps` for details.

Comment: @SatoKatsura , your suggestion seems to be working nice. Is there any need to run it as root?

Comment: If you only care about your own processes, then no.

Comment: So, @SatoKatsura , I assume running as `sudo` would show all users processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we wait for Sato Katsura to answer the question, this (his) method works fine:

```
ps ax -o command | sort | uniq -d
```